# UIWebView not loadRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have this code and not loading  this page i do not know what happen

in iPad dont work and only show a empty screen when webViewDidFinishLoad finish.

And the iPhone works fine whats wrong?

Because only this link dont works https://www.facebook.com/peopemexico

this is my code:

```
.h

@interface WebRedesIpad : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *propNavegador;



.m

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    _propNavegador.delegate=self;

    [_propNavegador loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/peopemexico"]]];

    }


    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    }
```

Comment: so you are saying it works on iPhone but not on iPad right?? If yes, I bet you have not attached webview to its variable in iPad storyboard...

Answer (score 0):

Have you written UIWebViewDelagte in the .h file of the same class?

Answer (score 0):

If it's working in iPhone and not in iPad then you must have not linked variable `propNavegador` to iPad storyboard/ NIB files.

You must have attached to only iPhone storyboard/ NIB files.

Please check and let me know.